# How to loop through Keras fit function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, models

To keep from having to write this 500 times:

```
model.fit(
      x[i],
      y[i],
      batch_size=batch,
      epochs=epochs,
      validation_split=0.05)
```

I would like to loop this through the number of datasets I'm fitting. However, when I do this, the first fit's metrics are as follows:

```
loss: nan - acc: 7.4635e-04 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

And every single time after that is runs, its metrics are:

```
loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Now I don't thnk having a `val_loss` and `val_acc` of 0 and nan is good, but at least there's `acc` but after the first fit, all of the metrics are basically null.

EDIT:

Here is my code for formatting my data. `x[i]` is all of the data, where `x[0]` would be the first entire dataset.

```
    x_train = [None] * len(os.listdir('/'))
    y_train = [None] * len(os.listdir('/'))
    x_test = [None] * len(os.listdir('/'))
    y_test = [None] * len(os.listdir('/'))


def format_data(data, seq_len, normalise_window):
    sequence_length = seq_len + 1
    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])

    if normalise_window:
        result = normalise_windows(result)

    result = np.array(result)


    row = round(0.85 * result.shape[0])
    train = result[:int(row), :]
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    x_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1]
    x_test = result[int(row):, :-1]
    y_test = result[int(row):, -1]

    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

    return [x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test]

for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir('/directory')):
        try:
          print"starting file :",filename
          data = pd.read_csv('directory/{0}'.format(filename), index_col=0, header=0)
          data['open'].replace('nan',np.nan)
          data.dropna()
          new = data['open'].tolist()


          x_train[i], y_train[i], x_test[i], y_test[i] = format_data(new, seq_len, True)
        except:
          pass

for i in range(len(x_train)):
        print"starting fit :",i,"of length",len(x_train)

        try:
          model.fit(
            x_train[i],
            y_train[i],
            batch_size=batch,
            epochs=epochs,
            validation_split=0.05)
        except:
          pass
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why are you trying to loop the over the fit function? What is the type of `x`?

Comment: `nan` loss can happen from a lot of things, your data, model, activations, target data, the way you pre-process. Does this happen say if you just fit `x[0]` and `y[0]`?

Comment: @ZiyadEdher x is a sequential dataset. I want to loop it so I don't have to copy and paste 500 of the fit function.

Comment: @nuric the first time (`x[0]`) it gives me these metrics; `loss: nan - acc: 7.4635e-04 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00` as stated in the op

Comment: What does `x[0]` represent? The first data point or a list of data points?

Comment: @CarsonP, please post `compile` method parameters.

Comment: @CarsonP, do you want to loop through fit results ?

Comment: @ZiyadEdher x[0] should be a whole dataset. Here the line where I create my data. `x_train[i], y_train[i], x_test[i], y_test[i] = format_data(new, seq_len, True)` And I loop that line thru all of the files in a directory.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut How do I compile method paramaters? And I want to loop thru the fitting. It's not the biggest deal that I'm not getting good metrics, I care that the model isn't being trained at all. It actually makes a whole model, but when I use this model to make predictions, it just comes out at a bunch of NaN's as predictions and I'm assuming that's because it's being trained incorrectly.

Comment: @ZiyadEdher I added in the OP my code for formatting my data.

Comment: @CarsonP your question is incomplete and therefore cannot be answered by anyone. Please post a minimal example so we can reproduce your results and thus maybe find the bug(s).

Comment: @jean Is what I just added enough to work?

Comment: @ZiyadEdher So I just tried doing it with 50 copied and pasted fit functions, and for some reason, it had the same problem. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Basically @CarsonP most of what you posted is useless for debugging. What I would have done is pull out x_train[0] and y_train[0] see if there is anything wrong with these values and try fitting whatever your model is(,which we don't know anything about btw) on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the for block and try inserting this code

```
model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_split=0.05)
```

I hope this might help you.
I guess "nan" for loss and val_loss because u are passing a single value to the model , try passing the tensor itself (hope u will get some value in loss n val_loss).

Comment: So I added alot of my code in the OP, `x[i]` is not a single value, it should be (at least to my current understanding) an entire set of data. The first for loop in my code shows how I'm populating `x` with data. When I remove the `try: except:` it still has the same problem.

Comment: Im not able to make out ur data since it is not present with me ,and keras takes the whole data in form of tensor.For y[] have done OHE(one hot encoding)